# Set images (from array) for buttons by their tag

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have an array of images in `viewDidLoad` method as follow :

```
images = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"make_fun.png",
                                       @"smile-2.png",
                                       @"cream_happy_ice.png",
                                       @"big_smile.png",
                                       @"fun.png",
                                       @"happy_santaclaus",
                                       @"make_fun.png",
                                       @"smile-2.png",
                                       @"cream_happy_ice.png",
                                       @"big_smile.png",
                                       @"fun.png",
                                       @"happy_santaclaus",nil];
```

This array contains name of images.
I have also 12 buttons on `storyboard` and I tagged all buttons from 0 to 11.

What i want to implement is very simple - when the user clicks on the one of the buttons its tag is used as index in images array to set the background of the button. This is my code :

```
- (IBAction)onClickButton:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;

   [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:[sender tag]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];  

}
```

But I get this error in the editor:

```
Thread 1 : EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code = 1, address = 0x1)
```

I have a look in many questions on stackoverflow by i can't find the solution.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Sorry but still the same error

Comment: did you put an exception breakpoint and try this. It might show you where exactly it crashes.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way, use `[button tag]` instead `[sender tag]`

```
- (IBAction)onClickButton:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;

   [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:images[button tag]]         
           forState:UIControlStateNormal];  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Use tag on button instead of sender. It may help you.

```
- (IBAction)onClickButton:(id)sender {

    UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;
   [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:[button tag]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the generic type `id` of `sender` doesn't know a property `tag`.
An easy solution is to use `UIButton` as parameter type

```
- (IBAction)onClickButton:(UIButton *)button {
   button.image = [UIImage imageNamed:images[button.tag] forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
}
```

and dot notation avoids a bunch of brackets.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure the UIImage instance in not nil

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:[button tag]];
if (image) {
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:[sender tag]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
} else {
    // something is wrong with the image you are trying to assign. 
}
```

if the image is indeed there, then try changing the button type from `System` to `Custom` in the interface builder